# Reset the function wrongly assigned as string in python using Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was practicing plotting when by mistake I assigned ylabel and title as below:

```
plt.ylabel = "No. of Hospitals"
plt.title = 'Hospitals by State'
```

This changed the two functions to string, as confirmed in the image below. (First blue circle)

Then I changed the statement to set these correctly to:

```
plt.ylabel("No. of Hospitals")
plt.title('Hospitals by State')
```

Now, I get the error
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

In one of the stackoverflow article, I learned once the function is wrongly assigned then only way to fix this is restart the kernel. I don't want to restart the kernel and run all 500+ jobs above this mistake. I also tried importing matplotlib and sns again by calling pyplot as plt2 that didn't work either. (Second Blue circle in the image).

I was wondering is there a way to reset the function back to normal from the string status now?

I do understand that I can write the dataframe of interest to a file and then read it back in the new notebook. However, I'm sure many will agree knowing the process and ability to reset the function back to normal will help many in future without costly work around(s).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may redefine them, like:

```py
plt.title = lambda *args, **kwargs: plt.gca().set_title(*args, **kwargs)
plt.ylabel = lambda *args, **kwargs: plt.gca().set_ylabel(*args, **kwargs)
```

See also the original code of [`matplotlib.pyplot.title`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/25b39d41d3528329b3e5164bbf71feb0d556af80/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2996) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/25b39d41d3528329b3e5164bbf71feb0d556af80/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L3011).